# Bijection between submodules of $M$ that contain $L$ and the submodules of $M/L$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

I asked the following question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951437/submodule-maximal-if-and-only-if-quotient-module-simple).

> Why is the case that a submodule $L$ of a module $M$ is maximal, among submodules of $M$ distinct from $M$, if and only if the quotient module $M/L$ is simple?

Mariano Suárez-Álvarez commented the following.

> It is because there is bijection between the submodules of $M$ that contain $L$ and the submodules of $M/L$.

How do I establish this bijection?

Comment: what do you mean "how do I see" here?

Comment: @ZelosMalum I've changed it to "how do I establish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bijection is fairly easy, let $K$ be a submodule in $M/L$ and $L\subset N$ a submodule of $M$ that contains $L$. We can easily see that $\pi(N)$ is a submodule, where $\pi$ is the quotient homomorphism. So it sends any submodule containing $L$ to a submodule of $M/L$. For the inverse, $\pi^{-1}(K)$. Let $x',y'\in K$ be given, they come in some form of $x+L$ and $y+L$, as it is a submodule we have that $x'+y'=x+L+y+L=x+y+L\in K$ and as such we have $x+y\in\pi^{-1}(K)$. For module production we show the same and establish that $\pi^{-1}(K)$ is a submodule, to see that it contains $L$ we notice that $K$ must contain the $0$ element which is the set $L$ for us in the quotient.

From there we see there is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks so much! One more question: how does this imply that a submodule $L$ of a module $M$ is maximal, among submodules of $M$ distinct from $M$, if and only if the quotient module $M/L$ is simple?

Comment: If the submodule is maximal there exists no proper submodules containing it and as such, with this bijection, then there exists no proper non-trivial submodules in the quotient. If there did exist a non-trivial proper submodule in the quotient it would imply by the bijection there exist a proper submodule containing $L$ which makes it not maximal